# Grails inline plugin notation for Java project dependencies?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I've successfully used Grails's inline / inplace plugin notation to develop my Grails app and several plugins concurrently. I only have to compile my Grails app and all the inline plugins get compiled too (great!):

`grails.plugin.location.myFooPlugin = '../plugins/foo-plugin'`

**Can I do the same thing for a Java dependency rather than a Grails plugin?**

Let's say I have some Java project that ultimately produces a JAR, but rather than compile and store the JAR in my Maven local repo I'd like to simply compile my Grails app and have the Java project's code also compiled as a result. Possible? If so, what are the rules, such as dir structure adherence? I might want to use Gradle or Maven, not sure.

Comment: I don't think this would work... Grails does a lot of magic to get automatic code updates to be compiled on the fly into a running app. This would not work with Java sources outside of Grails app (or inside for that matter). It might be possible with something like JRebel on top but I don't think Grails does it "out of the box".

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a java dependency in my Grails project with help of `/scripts/_Events.groovy`:

```
eventCompileStart = {
  projectCompiler.srcDirectories << "${basedir}/../your_java_proj/src".toString()
}
```

The java project will be compiled automatically along with e.g. `grails war` commando.